# Static class object reference

Tags: c#

I have one main form and a static class when i access static class member it gives me nullreference error . Previously it was working fine donot know what happend . Any one can suggest what is wrong.

code snap:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class myForm : Form
    {
        public myForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void myForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            My_Static_Data_Class.player_name="Demo Player"
        }
    } 

    public static class My_Static_Data_Class
    {
        public static string player_name = "";
    }
}
```

please help?

Comment: Please make more effort to format your code. The indentation is all over the place at the moment. The code you've provided won't give a NullReferenceException, either. Please show your full stack trace.

Comment: You are missing `;` behind `"Demo Player"`.

Comment: Provide compiling code that demonstrates the issue reproducibly. It sounds like nitpicking, but it's also important to follow [capitalization-](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx)(f.e. uppercase first letter in `player_name`) and [naming-conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx)(f.e. no underscores).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

You're either accessing the static class member before it was set to "Demo Player". For example, you are trying accessing My_Static_Data_Class.player_name in Program.cs code before it calls the main form from the Main[] method. Alternatively you're might be setting My_Static_Data_Class.player_name to null elsewhere in code and then accessing it.

Check all the references in code editor and follow it up. To do this, right click on My_Static_Data_Class.player_name in Visual Studio editor, and choose Find All References menu item.

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh added further explanation.